# How to put the current datetime in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How to put the current datetime in MySQL using PHP?

The result should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (r_date) VALUES ('the current datetime')");
```

The type of `r_date` is `datetime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field is a DATE or DATETIME, [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) will work:

```
INSERT INTO users (r_date) VALUES (NOW());");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the now() function insert current date of **MySQL** server.
If you need to insert server date you should use [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)